# How to create an array of objects with 2 arrays?

Tags: php

i'm trying to create an array of objects but its kinda hard for me to do it. Can you guys help me?

THis is what i have right now:

```
              $id_mercado = strip_tags($obj->idMercado);


                $sql    = "SELECT * FROM mercados WHERE id = $id_mercado";
                $stmt   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();

               $row  = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
               $siglas = explode("\n", $row->dicionario_familias_sigla);
               $significados = explode("\n", $row->dicionario_familias_significado);

               class Dicionario{
                public $siglas;
                public $significados;
                }

                $listaFiltros = new Dicionario(); 
                        $listaFiltros->siglas = $siglas;
                        $listaFiltros->significado = $significados;
```

So siglas is

```
["EX", "RO", "DI", "OR", "VE"]
```

Significado is

```
["Exoticos","Rosas","Diversos","Orquideas","Verdes"]
```

the output i want is:

```
0: {sigla: "EX", significado: "Exoticos"} 
1: {sigla: "RO", significado: "Rosas"} 
2: {sigla: "DI", significado: "Diversos"} 
3: {sigla: "OR", significado: "Orquedeas"}
4: {sigla: "VE", significado: "Verdes"}
```

UPDATE

```
for($i = 0; count($significados)> $i; $i++){
                $listaFiltros[] = (object) array('sigla' => $siglas[$i], 
                                                 'significado' => $significados[$i]);
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use PDO, but you can use the fields returned from your SELECT statement, populate the objects, and then push them to the array you want like this...

```
$myArr = []; 

$object = (object)[
    "sigla": $row->dicionario_familias_sigla,
    "significado": $row->dicionario_familias_significado
];

array_push($myArr, $object);
```

Comment: Sorry @jtylerm but i didn't understand

Comment: I updated my answer. In PHP, you can make objects without creating a class by casting an associative array as an object. If dicionario_familias_sigla and dicionario_familias_significado are the column names from the database table you're selecting from, then you can use those values to populate an object like I did above.